# Ajtai's Proof of Theorem 1 in 'Generating Hard Instances of Lattice Problems'

Tags: integer-lattice

My question pertains to the proof of Ajtai's main theorem in his groundbreaking 1996 paper, *[Generating hard instances of lattice problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/237814.237838)*, which indicates a connection between worst-case hard and average-case hard lattice problems.
This proof is  difficult for me to understand. Is there a clear exposition of this proof in the literature?

Comment: You can try reading more recent papers such as http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/average.pdf, or Oded Regev's lecture notes http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/averagecase.pdf (you might want to read the entire course).

Answer (score 8):

You can try reading more recent papers such as [Worst-case to Average-case Reductions based on Gaussian Measures](http://cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/average.pdf) by Miccancio and Regev, or Regev's  [lecture notes](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/averagecase.pdf) on the subject (you might want to read through the [entire course](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/)).

Answer (score 3):

Replying very late, I really like the exposition of Ajtai's proof in [this paper of Goldreich, Goldwasser and Halevi.](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/COL/cfh.pdf)